# Find the 2 max values for each factor in R

Tags: r, dataset, max, subset

I have a question about finding the two largest values of column C, for each unique ID in column A, then calculating the mean of column B. A sample of my data is here:

```
ID  layer   weight
1   0.6843629   0.35
1   0.6360772   0.70
1   0.6392318   0.14
2   0.3848640   0.05
2   0.3882660   0.30
2   0.3877026   0.10
2   0.3964194   0.60
2   0.4273218   0.02
2   0.3869507   0.12
3   0.4748541   0.07
3   0.5853659   0.42
3   0.5383678   0.10
3   0.6060287   0.60
4   0.4859274   0.08
4   0.4720740   0.48
4   0.5126481   0.08
4   0.5280899   0.48
5   0.7492097   0.07
5   0.7220433   0.35
5   0.8750000   0.10
5   0.8302752   0.50
6   0.4306283   0.10
6   0.4890895   0.25
6   0.3790714   0.20
6   0.5139686   0.50
6   0.3885678   0.02
6   0.4706815   0.05
```

For each ID, I want to calculate the mean value of layer, using only the rows where with the two highest weights.

I can do this with the following code in R:

```
ind.max1 <- ddply(index1, "ID", function(x) x[which.max(x$weight),]) 
    dt1 <- data.table(index1, key=c("layer"))
    dt2 <- data.table(ind.max1, key=c("layer"))
    index2 <- dt1[!dt2]
    ind.max2 <- ddply(index2, "ID", function(x) x[which.max(x$weight),])
ind.max.all <- merge(ind.max1, ind.max2, all=TRUE)
ind.ndvi.mean <- as.data.frame(tapply(ind.max.all$layer, list(ind.max.all$ID), mean))
```

This uses `ddply` to select the first highest weight value per ID and put into a dataframe with layer. Then remove these highest weight values from the original dataframe using `data.table`. I then repeat the `ddply` select max value, and merge the two max weight value dataframes into one. Finally, computing mean with `tapply`.
There must be a more efficient way to do this. Does anyone have any insight? Cheers.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569038/fastest-way-to-find-the-index-of-the-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in?lq=1

Comment: Are the two largest values guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, mean(layer[order(-weight)[1:2]]), by=ID]
 #   ID Meanlayer
 #1:  1 0.6602200
 #2:  2 0.3923427
 #3:  3 0.5956973
 #4:  4 0.5000819
 #5:  5 0.7761593
 #6:  6 0.5015291
```

- Order `weight` column in descending `order(-weight)`
- Select first two from the order created `[1:2]` by group `ID`
- subset the corresponding `layer` row based on the index `layer[order..]`
- Do the `mean`

---

Alternatively, in [1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) (current development version) or from the next version on, a function `setorder` is exported for reordering data.tables in any order, *by reference*:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3+
setorder(setDT(dat), ID, -weight) ## dat is now reordered as we require
dat[, mean(layer[1:min(.N, 2L)]), by=ID]
```

By ordering first, we avoid the call to `order()` for each group (unique value in `ID`). This'll be more advantageous with more groups. And `setorder()` is much more efficient than `order()` as it doesn't need to create a copy of your data.

Comment: @Arun. Thanks for the 1.9.3+ solution.  I guess I need to install the new version.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is a question for StackOverflow... anyway!
Don't know if the version below is efficient enough for you...

```
s.ind<-tapply(df$weight,df$ID,function(x) order(x,decreasing=T))
val<-tapply(df$layer,df$ID,function(x) x)

foo<-function(x,y) list(x[y][1:2])
lapply(mapply(foo,val,s.ind),mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it. Assuming the data is called `dat`,

```
> sapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x) { 
      with(x, {
          mean(layer[ weight %in% rev(sort(weight))[1:2] ])
          })
      })
#         1         2         3         4         5         6 
# 0.6602200 0.3923427 0.5956973 0.5000819 0.7761593 0.5015291
```

You'll likely want to include `na.rm = TRUE` as the second argument to `mean` to account for any rows that contain `NA` values.

Alternatively, `mapply` is probably faster, and has the exact same code just in a different order,

```
mapply(function(x) { 
      with(x, {
          mean(layer[ weight %in% rev(sort(weight))[1:2] ])
          })
      }, split(dat, dat$ID))
```