# How to look for the closest place based on coordinates

Tags: r, distance, spatial

I have a main database with several weather stations. Each station has coordinates in Decimal degrees. Below just an example, as coordinates were made up

```
stationid lon lat
1a        80  104
1b        84  110
1c        85  111
```

Aside, i have a smaller dataset with places. i require to match each place to the closest weather station from the main database (hopefully with a specified distance threshold)

```
  place lon   lat 
  2a    80.5  104.1
  3b    83    109
```

So the resulting smaller database will show

```
  place lon   lat    stationid
  2a    80.5  104.1  1a
  3b    83    109    1b
```

will appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `geosphere::distm` + `max.col`

```
df2$stationid <- df1$stationid[max.col(-distm(rev(df2[-1]), rev(df1[-1])))]
```

which gives

```
  place  lat   lon stationid
1    2a 80.5 104.1        1a
2    3b 83.0 109.0        1b
```

Comment: @AndresMora You can read about the usage of ``distm` by typing `?distm`. It is said " 
longitude/latitude of point(s). Can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object". I think your `lon` and `lat` names should be switched.

Comment: Im giving this a try right now but getting `Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : latitude < -90`. My coordinates data is in decimal degrees. can that be the issue?

Comment: Just fixed that. I guess it was the lon lat order. Now i get `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 73.0 Gb`

Comment: @AndresMora Perhaps you have a super big dataset

Comment: @AndresMora If you don't want to have that memory space error, you can try `for` loops for finding the closest point. That would be slow but safe.

Comment: hows the "closest" point picked? what distance criteria does your approach use?

Comment: @AndresMora I used `distGeo`, which is default in `distm`

Comment: Maybe: [For each point, distance to nearest point in second dataset in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333747/for-each-point-distance-to-nearest-point-in-second-dataset-in-r). There OP seems to have the same issue: "I can do the naive implementation by _calculating all pairwise distances_ using `gDistance` and taking the min [like in the answer here], but I have some huge datasets and was looking for something more efficient"

Comment: @Henrik Good recommendation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You are welcome! But eventually it seems like `Error: cannot allocate vector` wasn't a problem for OP after all ;) Cheers