# find number of points within a radius in R using lon and lat coordinates

Tags: r

I have a set of points with longitude and latitude coordinates.
I want to find out the number of points within a specific radius from each point.
I have looked at the RANN and FNN packages and the only relevant function I found is the nn2() in the RANN package. though, I do not want to preset the maximum or minimum points that have to be identified (k variable in the nn2 function). in addition, even though I have tried several different values for k(number of points) and radius in nn2 I always get the same results. even when the radius is set to very small or zero.
here's an example of the code I've used

```
points<- nn2(mydata, k=100, radius = 0.02)
```

any ideas of how to do this in R?

Comment: Could you include the code you tried in the question (verbatim, not a description). Also, the question is not precisely defined. Do you mean within a distance on the earth's surface. If so you can find other questions that explain how to calculate geographic distance between two points. Then subset all that have distance less than x. Othe possible interpretation is within a spherical radius in 3d space, or within a planar radius on a projected map surface.

Comment: example code included. I have managed to calculate distances between points, using this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977720/r-finding-closest-neighboring-point-and-number-of-neighbors-within-a-given-rad. 
however, even if the question asks something similar, it is not answered there.
and yes I am trying to find the number of points within a radius on the earth's surface. I am looking for all the points included in all radiuses of all points in the dataset

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could still improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get what you want from `nn2`, you need to:

1. Specify the `searchtype` to be `"radius"`. By not specifying the `searchtype`, the `searchtype` is set to `standard` and the `radius` input is ignored.
2. Specify `k` to be `nrow(mydata)` because `k` is the maximum number of nearest neighbors to compute.

The manner in which you are calling `nn2` will return the `100` nearest neighbors in `mydata` for each point in `mydata`. Consequently, you will get the same result for any `radius`. For example:

```
library(RANN)
set.seed(123)

## simulate some data
lon = runif(100, -99.1, -99)
lat = runif(100, 33.9, 34)

## data is a 100 x 2 matrix (can also be data.frame)
mydata <- cbind(lon, lat)

radius <- 0.02   ## your radius
res <- nn2(mydata, k=nrow(mydata), searchtype="radius", radius = radius)
## prints total number of nearest neighbors (for all points) found using "radius"
print(length(which(res$nn.idx>0)))
##[1] 1224
res1 <- nn2(mydata, k=100, radius = radius) 
## prints total number of nearest neighbors (for all points) found using your call
print(length(which(res1$nn.idx>0)))
##[1] 10000

radius <- 0.03   ## increase radius
res <- nn2(mydata, k=nrow(mydata), searchtype="radius", radius = radius)
## prints total number of nearest neighbors (for all points) found using "radius"
print(length(which(res$nn.idx>0)))
##[1] 2366
res1 <- nn2(mydata, k=100, radius = radius)
## prints total number of nearest neighbors (for all points) found using your call
print(length(which(res1$nn.idx>0)))
##[1] 10000
```

Note that according to its documentation `?nn2`, `nn2` returns a list with two elements:

1. `nn.idx`: a `nrow(query) x k` matrix where each row contains the row indices of the `k` nearest neighbors in `mydata` to the point at that row in the collection of query points in `query`. In both of our calls, `query=mydata`. When called with `searchtype="radius"`, if there are `m < k` neighbors within the given radius, then `k - m` of those index values will be set to `0`. Since the set of query points is the same as `mydata`, the index to the point itself will be included.
2. `nn.dist`: a `nrow(query) x k` matrix where each element contains the Euclidean distances for the corresponding nearest neighbor in `nn.idx`. Here, if the corresponding element in `nn.idx` is `0`, then the value in `nn.dist` is set to 1.340781e+154.

With your call, you get `100` nearest neighbors for each point in `mydata`, hence `length(which(res1$nn.idx>0))==10000` no matter what the `radius` is in the example.

Finally, you should note that because `nn2` returns two `nrow(mydata) x nrow(mydata)` in your case, it can very easily overwhelm your memory if you have a lot of points.

---

**Updated** to specifically produce the result of getting the count of neighbors within a given radius.

To compute the number of neighbors within a `radius` of each point in the data, call `nn2` as such

```
res <- nn2(mydata, k=nrow(mydata), searchtype="radius", radius = radius)
```

Then, do this:

```
count <- rowSums(res$nn.idx > 0) - 1
```

Notes:

1. Since `query=mydata` and `k=nrow(mydata)` the resulting `res$nn.idx` will be `nrow(mydata) x nrow(mydata)` as explained above.
2. Each row `i` of `res$nn.idx` **corresponds** to row `i` in `query`, which is the `i`-th point in `query=mydata`. Call this `i`-th point `p[i]`.
3. Each row `i` of `res$nn.idx` **contains** the row indices of the neighbors of `p[i]` **AND** zeroes to fill that row in the matrix (because not all points in `mydata` will be within the `radius` of `p[i]`).
4. Therefore, the number of neighbors of `p[i]` can be found by finding those values in the row that are greater than `0` and then counting them. This is what `rowSums(res$nn.idx > 0)` does for each row of `res$nn.idx`.
5. Lastly, because `query=mydata`, the point being queried is in the count itself. That is, a point is the nearest neighbor to itself. Therefore subtract `1` from these counts to exclude that.

The resulting `count` will be a vector of the counts. The `i`-th element is the number of neighbors within the `radius` to the `i`-th point in `query=mydata`.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Though I do not understand two things. first is the print function. what is the difference of printing results using radius and call?
second: according to your notations, what I understand is that as far as I am using mydata as query, overlapping points are included in the result. how can I find the number of points within the same dataset? to simplify this: I want to find the number of points, for every point within the given radius of one dataset

Comment: @Alex: I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify your second question. For your first question, I use `print` to simply output the result of the computation from a script to the console in RStudio. There is really no need for `print`. Also, I was outputting the difference between the answer and how you were calling `nn2` to illustrate why you reported that the answer seems always to be the same no matter what value the `radius` is set.

Comment: thank you so much! that's a solid answer!
everything is clear now