# Finding which rows correspond to the output of a function value/total

Tags: r

My data is similar to the following:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   offense [7]
    lon   lat offense           
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>             
1 -95.3  29.8 aggravated assault
2 -95.4  29.9 auto theft        
3 -95.3  29.8 burglary          
4 -95.5  29.7 murder            
5 -95.4  30.0 rape              
6 -95.5  29.8 robbery           
7 -95.4  29.8 theft
```

I can run the following

```
cbind(df, X = rowSums(distm(df[,1:2], fun = distHaversine) / 1000 <= 10))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   offense [7]
    lon   lat offense                X
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
1 -95.3  29.8 aggravated assault     3
2 -95.4  29.9 auto theft             2
3 -95.3  29.8 burglary               3
4 -95.5  29.7 murder                 1
5 -95.4  30.0 rape                   2
6 -95.5  29.8 robbery                1
7 -95.4  29.8 theft                  3
```

Which gives me the number of points within a radius of 10km according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874731/calculating-number-of-points-within-a-certain-radius).

What I would like to know is how to modify that function to give me which rows correspond to each point within a radius. The first row has a value of `3`, this value might be made up of an observation from rows `2`, `4` and `7` for example.

It might look like:

```
    lon   lat offense                X    points

1 -95.3  29.8 aggravated assault     3   c(2,4,7)
2 -95.4  29.9 auto theft             2   c(2,3)
3 -95.3  29.8 burglary               3   c(4,5,7)
```

Once I have these I would like to create lists such that row `1` would be a list containing lists of `1`, `2`, `4` and `7`. (However this might be a different quesiton)

Data:

```
library(geosphere)
library(ggmap)
df <- crime %>% 
  group_by(offense) %>% 
  sample_n(1) %>% 
  select(lon, lat, offense)
```

Comment: Is the `crime` data from `geosphere`

Comment: Sorry, its from `library(ggmap)`

Comment: The values are not reproducible as I get different values

Comment: Perhaps `m1 <- which(distm(df[,1:2], fun = distHaversine) / 1000 <= 10, arr.ind = TRUE);
split(m1[, 'row'], m1[, 'col'])`

Comment: Thats probably because of the `sample_n(1)`. In my actual data each row is a unique point, if I did not `group_by(offense)` I would get `robbery` maybe 3 times, I guess I could have used `head(1)` or something.

Comment: This looks good, thanks! how can I 1) paste these values into a `df` column as `c(1,2,3)...` and 2) extract the information from the rows from which the `split(m1...` out comes from and put the data into lists.

Comment: You can assign a `list` column with `df$points <- split(m1[, 'row'], m1[, 'col'])` but as the values are different, couldn't test