# Find nearest cities from the data frame to the specific location

Tags: r, spatial

Below dataframe contains the information about the lat, long , state and city. I want to find 
the three nearest cities for every city given in the dataframe. For example, from the below
dataframe, Oklahoma city and Colarado SPringd nearest to Albuquerque, So three nearest city to Albuquerque should be 
saved in other dataframe named nearest_AL(I don't know how to get this result, that'y I tried to gave an idea by creating a data frame).

```
dataframe<-data.frame(long=c("-106.61291","-81.97224","-84.42770","-72.68604","-97.60056","-104.70261"),
  lat=c("35.04333","33.37378","33.64073","41.93887","35.39305","38.80171"),
  state=c("NM","GA","GA","TX","OK","CO"),
  city=c("Albuquerque","Augusta","Atlanta","Windsor Locks","Oklahoma City","Colarado Springs")
)

nearest_Al<-data.frame(long=c("-97.60056","-104.70261"),
                      lat=c("35.39305","38.80171"),
                      state=c("OK","CO"),
                      city=c("Oklahoma City","Colarado Springs")
)
```

This same thing I have to perform on the dataframe which contains rows 500k and around 100 locations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977720/r-finding-closest-neighboring-point-and-number-of-neighbors-within-a-given-rad

Comment: I think Windsor Locks is in Connecticut, not in Texas, but it does not affect my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea. `dataframe2` is the final output. The `Near_City` column shows the top three closest cities for each city in the `city` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

# Create example data frame
dataframe<-data.frame(long=c("-106.61291","-81.97224","-84.42770","-72.68604","-97.60056","-104.70261"),
                      lat=c("35.04333","33.37378","33.64073","41.93887","35.39305","38.80171"),
                      state=c("NM","GA","GA","TX","OK","CO"),
                      city=c("Albuquerque","Augusta","Atlanta","Windsor Locks","Oklahoma City","Colarado Springs"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Create spatial point data frame object
dataframe_sp <- dataframe %>%
  mutate(long = as.numeric(long), lat = as.numeric(lat))
coordinates(dataframe_sp) <- ~long + lat

# Convert to sf object
dataframe_sf <- st_as_sf(dataframe_sp)

# Set projection
st_crs(dataframe_sf) <- 4326

# Calculate the distance
dist_m <- st_distance(dataframe_sf, dataframe_sf)

# Select the closet three cities
# Remove the first row, and then select the first three rows
index <- apply(dist_m, 1, order)
index <- index[2:nrow(index), ]
index <- index[1:3, ]

# Rep each city by three
dataframe2 <- dataframe[rep(1:nrow(dataframe), each = 3), ]

# Process the dataframe based on index, store the results in Near_City column
dataframe2$Near_City <- dataframe[as.vector(index), ]$city
```

#### Update

We can further create the output the OP wants.

```
dataframe3 <- dataframe[as.vector(index), ]
dataframe3$TargetCity <- dataframe2$city

nearest_city_list <- split(dataframe3, f = dataframe3$TargetCity)
```

Now each "Target City" is an element on the list `nearest_city_list`. To Access the data, we can access the list element using the target city name. Here is an example pulling out the results of Albuquerque:

```
nearest_city_list[["Albuquerque"]]
        long      lat state             city  TargetCity
6 -104.70261 38.80171    CO Colarado Springs Albuquerque
5  -97.60056 35.39305    OK    Oklahoma City Albuquerque
3  -84.42770 33.64073    GA          Atlanta Albuquerque
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little slow with all your data but it does the trick

```
dataframe<-data.frame(long=as.numeric(c("-106.61291","-81.97224","-84.42770","-72.68604","-97.60056","-104.70261")),
                  lat=as.numeric(c("35.04333","33.37378","33.64073","41.93887","35.39305","38.80171")),
                  state=c("NM","GA","GA","TX","OK","CO"),
                  city=c("Albuquerque","Augusta","Atlanta","Windsor Locks","Oklahoma City","Colarado Springs"))

library(sp)
library(rgeos)


coordinates(dataframe) <- ~long+lat
dist_cities <- gDistance(dataframe, byid=T)

dist_cities_rank<-data.frame()
for(i in seq(1,dim(dist_cities)[1])){
   dist_cities_rank<-rbind(dist_cities_rank,rank(as.numeric(dist_cities[i,])))
}

three_close_cities<-list()
for(i in seq(1,dim(dataframe)[1])){

   three_close_cities[[i]]<-
   list(test_city=dataframe[i,],cbind(dataframe[which(dist_cities_rank[i,]<=4&dist_cities_rank[i,]!=1),],
                                                          dist_cities[i,which(dist_cities_rank[i,]<=4&dist_cities_rank[i,]!=1)]))
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `coordinates(dataframe) <- ~long+lat`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you

I made a `distance` function that accepts `x` (longitude of current row in `dataframe`), `y` (latitude of current row in `dataframe`), and `dataframe`. It returns the top 2 nearest cities (excluding the target city)

```
 dist <- function(xi, yi, z) {
              z <- z %>% 
                     mutate(dist = sqrt((as.double(as.character(z$long)) - as.double(as.character(xi)))^2 + (as.double(as.character(z$lat)) - as.double(as.character(yi)))^2)) %>%
                     arrange(dist) %>%            # distance
                     slice(2:3)                   # top 2 nearest cities

              return(z)
         }
```

#### tidyverse solution

```
 library(tidyverse)
 mod <- dataframe %>%
          mutate(copylong = long, copylat = lat) %>%     # make copy of longitude and latitude to nest
          nest(copylong, copylat) %>%                    # nest copy
          mutate(data = map(data, ~ dist(.x$copylong, .x$copylat, dataframe)))
```

To save only the nearest cities as a separate data frame

```
 desired <- map_df(1:nrow(mod), ~ mod$data[.x][[1]])
```

#### Output

```
         long      lat  state             city      dist
 1 -104.70261 38.80171     CO Colarado Springs  4.216001
 2  -97.60056 35.39305     OK    Oklahoma City  9.019133
 3  -84.42770 33.64073     GA          Atlanta  2.469928
 4  -72.68604 41.93887     TX    Windsor Locks 12.633063
 5  -81.97224 33.37378     GA          Augusta  2.469928
 6  -97.60056 35.39305     OK    Oklahoma City 13.288900
 # etc
```

#### Extra

If you want to keep the original database and the nearest cities

```
 mod <- dataframe %>%
          mutate(copylong = long, copylat = lat) %>%     # make copy of longitude and latitude to nest
          nest(copylong, copylat) %>%                    # nest copy
          mutate(data = map(data, ~ dist(.x$copylong, .x$copylat, dataframe))) %>%
          unnest(data)
```

Extra output

```
         long      lat  state             city      long1     lat1 state1            city1      dist
 1 -106.61291 35.04333     NM      Albuquerque -104.70261 38.80171     CO Colarado Springs  4.216001
 2 -106.61291 35.04333     NM      Albuquerque  -97.60056 35.39305     OK    Oklahoma City  9.019133
 3  -81.97224 33.37378     GA          Augusta  -84.42770 33.64073     GA          Atlanta  2.469928
 4  -81.97224 33.37378     GA          Augusta  -72.68604 41.93887     TX    Windsor Locks 12.633063
```

#### Split into named list

```
 L <- split(mod, mod$city)
 names(L) <- dataframe$city
```

Comment: Will this solution create separate dataframes for different cities? For example, checking 3 nearest cities for Boston, store them into different data frame named "Boston_city". If suppose Hartford comes, find three nearest cities to Hartford save it to different data frame named "Hartford_city"

Comment: The values in the `dist` column seem to be too small. Notice that in the `dataframe`, `lat` and `long` are factors. For example, if you do `as.double(dataframe$long)`, it returns integers representing the factor levels. This may not be the number you want to use to calculate the distance.

Comment: One more question, if we have 3  nearest cities for example Colorado Springs, Colorado Springs and Augusta. Then, how to get only Colarado Springs and Augusta.So, if nearest city occur more than once for the same given location, remove one. Please help!!!

Comment: Example:                                                                                                                             long      lat  state             city      long1     lat1 state1
 -106.61291 35.04333     NM      Albuquerque -104.70261 38.80171     CO
-106.61291 35.04333     NM      Albuquerque -104.70261 38.80171     CO
 -81.97224 33.37378     GA          Augusta  -84.42770 33.64073     GA
 -81.97224 33.37378     GA          Augusta -106.61291 35.04333     NM            I want Colorado Springs only once. @Chi Pak

Comment: Thanks for the update, but numbers in dist still seem to be small. In addition, perhaps I missed something but I don' t know how to interpret your output. What does the second row of your extra output mean? What is the relationship between Albuquerque and Augusta?

Comment: @ycw, I'll look into this afternoon when I have more time but I think you have to be right, my values are too small...the second row of the extra output is *supposed to be* the top 2 nearest cities to the target city. So Alburquerque *should be* the 2nd nearest city to Augusta.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The second nearest city to Alburquerque is Oklahoma City based on the coordinates the OP provided. You may want to look deeper into this.