# Find distance between two cities using Haversine Formula in R with custom function

Tags: r, function, distance, geocoding, haversine

I'm trying to find the distance between two points using R. Though I've seen other answers ([Find nearest cities from the data frame to the specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576214/find-nearest-cities-from-the-data-frame-to-the-specific-location)), I want to use a specific formula to calculate distance in miles. On another site (https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/), I found this code in Java that gives the correct distance in their GUI:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2 
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
d = 3961 * c
```

I then converted this to a function in R:

```
geo_distance <- function(lon2, lon1, lat2, lat1){
  dlon <- lon2 - lon1
  dlat <- lat2 - lat1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
  d <- 3961 * c
  d
}

#The wrong number of miles from Hong Kong to Grand Canyon
geo_distance(114.17, -112.11, 22.31, 36.11)

#The wrong number of miles from Hong Kong to the Bangkok
geo_distance(114.17, 100.50, 22.31, 13.75)
```

However, it gives the wrong answer for some locations. For instance, the longitude and latitude of Hong Kong, China is 114.17 and 22.31, for the Grand Canyon, USA they're -112.11 and 36.11, and finally for Bangkok, Thailand they're 100.50 and 13.75.

On the website, it correctly says that Hong Kong and Bangkok are **1075** miles away, and Hong Kong and the Grand Canyon are **7399** miles away. In contrast, my code says that Hong Kong is **8078** miles away from Bangkok and only **4886** miles away from the Grand Canyon!

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert degrees to radians.

Distance from Hong Kong to the Grand Canyon

```
geo_distance(114.17*pi/180, -112.11*pi/180, 22.31*pi/180, 36.11*pi/180)

#[1] 7399.113
```

Also check the geosphere package and the function `distHaversine`

```
HongKong <- c(114.17, 22.31)
GrandCanyon <- c(-112.11, 36.11)

distHaversine(HongKong, GrandCanyon, r=6378137)
#[1] 11914303 distance in metres

distHaversine(HongKong, GrandCanyon, r=3961)
#[1] 7399.113 distance in miles
```