# Distance between latitude and longitude in two separate datasets

Tags: r, gps, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude

I would like to look at aid effectiveness, by looking at whether 1) the aid projects are placed were the child mortality is the highest and 2) If a respondents geographical proximity to a project reduces child mortality. I have two datasets. Dataset1 contains the latitude and longitude of aid-projects, and dataset 2 contains the latitude and longitude of the respondents (they are put inside clusters in order to not reveal their identity). I would like to set a radius of 25km from each respondent (data2) and see how many projects are within this radius, and the name of these projects. I have seen tips on how to calculate distances within the same dataset ([R - Finding closest neighboring point and number of neighbors within a given radius, coordinates lat-long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977720/r-finding-closest-neighboring-point-and-number-of-neighbors-within-a-given-rad)), but not a good tip on how to calculate the distance between two datasets. Does anyone have any insights as to how I might solve this problem? I have some experience with R, but I´m still pretty newbie! The datasets contains 1593 aid-projects and 267 respondent-clusters. Examples of tree longitude/latitude-coordinates are given below:

Dataset 1 - Aid projects - Latitude, longitude (0.75 , 34.08333 ; 2.85604 , 32.43001 ; 1.78481 , 33.59432)

Dataset 2 - Respondents data (clusters)- latitude, longitude (2.34240627, 32.64138 ; 2.18839338, 32.65868; 2.04988464, 32.87160)

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Best regards,

Synnøve

Comment: I would make a 2D density map of one variable and overlay the data for the second set. Are there any obvious patterns?

Comment: Hi, it would make it easier for us if you provided a snapshot of your data so we can easily work with it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info). You'll need to create a data set in which your aid projects as well as responsents appear as pairs, along with their respective coordinates. From there on out, it will be relatively easy to calculate distances. I am sure you will get help if you make it a little easier for us!

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the quick response! It is unfortunately not quite clear to me what you mean by a snapshot of my data. Do you want more latitude/longitude coordinates? And how should I have the projects and respondents appear as pairs? I have managed to calculate the distance to the nearest aid project for each respondent, but not to all within the radius of 25km. Thanks again for the help!
- Synnøve