# Is there a Python function for finding the data point in one set that's closest to the data points in another set?

Tags: python

I have two datasets containing latitudes, longitudes and locations.  I would like to link one dataset (the weather stations) to another (the main dataset).  But the main dataset has latitude/longitude combinations that don't match up directly to the weather station dataset.  Is there a way I can use some sort of nearest neighbor algorithm to find the closest weather station to each of my data points?

Comment: Take the `min` of the other dataset with a `key` that expresses the distance from the data point in question.

Comment: iterate over the weather stations and pick the one with the minimum distance to your datapoint. You will want to use a geodesic distance for that problem

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037569/1566221) is relevant. The standard Python library has no such function. Third-party libraries may exist, but SO doesn't allow questions asking for software recommendations. A geographical database might a better long-term solution.