# Find closest Zip Code to another from two data tables in R

Tags: r, data.table, zipcode

I have two separate data tables that I want to find the closet zip code from one data table to the other.  From the SiteZip table, I want the zip codes to loop through the ConsumerZip table to obtain the shortest distance between zip codes.  I used the zipcodeR package to assign lat and long to it.  The two tables are below.  The first table are the locations of stores.  The other table are customer locations.  I want to be able to create a single table that shows the closest store for each customer.  I have researched for a couple days and haven't found many requests that match what I'm looking for.  Ultimately I would map the store locations with a density circle by customer location.  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

````
head(StoreZip)
   Zip  Store         Address1        City State   lat    lng
1: 01026 11111 151 South Street  Cummington    MA 42.48 -72.93
2: 01040 11112    303 Beech St.     Holyoke    MA 42.22 -72.64
3: 01104 11113  417 Liberty St. Springfield    MA 42.13 -72.57
4: 01104 11114    2155 Main St. Springfield    MA 42.13 -72.57
5: 01301 11115   55 Federal St.  Greenfield    MA 42.63 -72.59
6: 01301 11116     1 Arch Place  Greenfield    MA 42.63 -72.59```

```head(CustomersZip)
    Zip         ID         Address1       City    State lat    lng
1: 01001    65484654805 1548 MAIN STREET AGAWAM    MA 42.07 -72.63
2: 01001    64846124846    569 MAPLE ST  AGAWAM    MA 42.07 -72.63
3: 01001    68421548945 68 PLANTATION DR AGAWAM    MA 42.07 -72.63
4: 01001    84051545484   154 South DR   AGAWAM    MA 42.07 -72.63
5: 01001    97545154848   985 Main St    AGAWAM    MA 42.07 -72.63
6: 01002    64841515484    54 KING ST    PELHAM    MA 42.38 -72.52
````

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525670/find-closest-points-from-data-set-b-to-point-in-data-set-a-using-lat-long-in-r/57526673#57526673

Comment: Are you looking for the `Haversine` distance between zip codes?

Comment: more specifically, `geosphere::distHaversine`?

Comment: `SiteZip --> StoreZip`?

Comment: A zip code is not defined by a single point in space, so the distance between two *zip codes* is too vague. You may choose to calculate the distance between (say) the *observed* center points for each zip code, or from each Store's lat/lon to each Customer's lat/lon (a bit more computation).

Comment: @r2evans Yes I was trying to use the geosphere package to calculate this.  I have found a couple similar examples, but not with two separate tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution for mapping each `CustomersZip$ID` with the closest `StoreZip$Store`:

```r
library(data.table)
# library(geosphere) # distHaversine
CustomersZip[
  , Store := StoreZip$Store[
      which.min(geosphere::distHaversine(
        cbind(first(lng), first(lat)),
        StoreZip[, cbind("lng", "lat"), with = FALSE])) ]
  , by = ID ]

CustomersZip
#      Zip          ID   lat    lng Store
#    <int>      <char> <num>  <num> <int>
# 1:  1001 65484654805 42.07 -72.63 11113
# 2:  1001 64846124846 42.07 -72.63 11113
# 3:  1001 68421548945 42.07 -72.63 11113
# 4:  1001 84051545484 42.07 -72.63 11113
# 5:  1001 97545154848 42.07 -72.63 11113
# 6:  1002 64841515484 42.38 -72.52 11112
```

Walk-through:

- `distHaversine` operates on two arguments, typically matrices (or frames) with two columns each; how it calculates distances depends on the number of points in each of its arguments `p1` and `p2`:

  - if `p1` has one point, then it calculates all `p2` points to the individual `p1` point; similarly if `p2` has one point;
  - if `p1` and `p2` have the same number of points, it calculates the distance point-wise, so that row1 with row1, row2 with row2, etc; it does *not* do a cartesian expansion of "row1 with row1,row2,row3,...", "row2 with row1,row2,row3,...", so that has to happen externally
- because of that, we work one customer at a time, and find the store with the minimum distance (`which.min`) and store its `Store` id
- though not a factor with this sample data, I chose to group this by `CustomersZip$ID` and use just the `first` lat/lng found for that customer; if it's possible that a customer will have different points, then remove the `first` calls, and group with `by = seq_len(nrow(CustomersZip))` instead; if this step is unnecessary, it will still calculate the same results, the only loss will be some efficiency by calculating the same distances multiple times

---

Reusable data (a subset of what is in the question):

```r
StoreZip <- fread("
  Zip Store   lat    lng
01026 11111 42.48 -72.93
01040 11112 42.22 -72.64
01104 11113 42.13 -72.57
01104 11114 42.13 -72.57
01301 11115 42.63 -72.59
01301 11116 42.63 -72.59")

CustomersZip <- fread("
  Zip      ID       lat    lng
01001 65484654805 42.07 -72.63
01001 64846124846 42.07 -72.63
01001 68421548945 42.07 -72.63
01001 84051545484 42.07 -72.63
01001 97545154848 42.07 -72.63
01002 64841515484 42.38 -72.52", colClasses = list(character="ID"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked perfectly!  After reviewing the entire data set I realized I need to bring in the ZCTA database for more accurate zip codes.  I really appreciate you explaining your process.  I understand what I was doing wrong, and your explanation really helped me to understand the geosphere package better.