# In R, how do I identify which two rows have minimum distance in my (x,y) dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, distance, latitude-longitude, minimum

In R, I have a dataframe with x,y as lat,long. How do I find which rows get the minimum distance and assign a number in a new column to show this? An simple example below shows the two rows,  (5,3) and (5,2), that have a minimum distance and Column C gives them the same number grouping.

[image: df]

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21977720/903061) should get you most of the way there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may need `distm` from package `library(geosphere)`

```
library(geosphere)
xy <- setNames(data.frame(rbind(c(0,0),c(90,90),c(10,10),c(-120,-45))),c("lon","lat"))
d <- distm(xy)
inds <- which(min(d[d>0])==d,arr.ind = TRUE)
out <- cbind(xy,C = NA)
out$C[inds[,"row"]] <- 1
```

which gives

```
> out
   lon lat  C
1    0   0  1
2   90  90 NA
3   10  10  1
4 -120 -45 NA
```

**Dummy data**

```
> dput(xy)
structure(list(lon = c(0, 90, 10, -120), lat = c(0, 90, 10, -45
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Once I identify the two associated rows, how would I go about making a column that categorizes those two points?  Can I map those results back to the original dataframe?

Comment: Thank you. From here, how would I iterate that for the rest of the points? So I want to find the next minimum distance and group those points. The part I'm trying to especially understand is, it is also comparing the minimum distance between a point and the newly grouped points .

Comment: @Kate I guess you can remove the found pairs from the data frame and do the same thing again to find the next pairs with the minimum distance