# R Spatstat: Identify nearest neighbours for further use

Tags: r, gis, spatstat

I have a dataframe with 488 GPS points (long and lat). For each 488 points I would like to find their 2 closest neighbours.

So far I have created a point pattern object and computed the distance from the nearest two points (below). However, I would like to go a step further and be able to identify these nearest points by their ID from the original dataset.

Currently, my script works like:

```
# 1. store x and y coords in two vectors
lon <- data$longitude
lat <- data$latitude

# 2. create two vectors xrange and yrange with dimensions of triangle that contain all points
xrange <- range(lon, na.rm=T)
yrange <- range(lat, na.rm=T)

# 3. create ppp
lf <- ppp(lon, lat, xrange, yrange)

plot(lf)

nndist(lf, k = 1:2)
```

Giving me (example of top 5 results):

```
             dist.1       dist.2
  [1,] 1.426925e-03 0.0017007414
  [2,] 1.017287e-03 0.0015574895
  [3,] 6.502012e-04 0.0010172867
  [4,] 6.502012e-04 0.0007202307
  [5,] 7.202307e-04 0.0010472445
```

But I would like to be able to link this back to the "hhid" from the original dataset to something like this:

```
  hhid         dist.1  dist.1.hhid         dist.2     dist.1.hhid
  1    1.426925e-03             7  0.0017007414                 3
  2    1.017287e-03             6  0.0015574895                 4
  3    6.502012e-04            10  0.0010172867                 5
  4    6.502012e-04             2  0.0007202307                 8
  5    7.202307e-04             1  0.0010472445                13
```

First 20 rows of original dataset :

```
structure(list(hhid = c(2004L, 2006L, 2009L, 2012L, 2013L, 2020L, 
2022L, 2023L, 2028L, 2029L, 2035L, 2036L, 2043L, 2046L, 2047L, 
2059L, 2062L, 2063L, 2065L, 2066L), longitude = c(-1.478302479, 
-1.477469802, -1.476488709, -1.476146936, -1.47547996, -1.475799441, 
-1.475903392, -1.476232767, -1.476053953, -1.477196693, -1.476906657, 
-1.478778243, -1.480723381, -1.433436394, -1.433033824, -1.428791046, 
-1.431989908, -1.432058454, -1.43134892, -1.430848002), latitude = c(12.10552216, 
12.10700512, 12.10673618, 12.10618305, 12.10645485, 12.10846806, 
12.1080761, 12.10830975, 12.11114883, 12.11076546, 12.11197853, 
12.11345387, 12.10725021, 12.1183548, 12.11699867, 12.11466122, 
12.1154108, 12.11545277, 12.11554337, 12.11567497)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be good an extension of the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977720/r-finding-closest-neighboring-point-and-number-of-neighbors-within-a-given-rad). Building off of that question's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21981693/12109788) to extend to your specific situation examining the closest two neighbors, you could do:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
# dput structure in question assigned as "df"

spatialDF <- df
coordinates(spatialDF) <- ~longitude + latitude
dists <- gDistance(spatialDF, byid = TRUE)
min.2dists <- apply(dists, 1, function(x) order(x, decreasing = FALSE)[2:3])

# closest
df$hhid1 <- df[min.2dists[1,],"hhid"]
df$dist1 <- apply(dists, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = FALSE)[2])

# second closest
df$hhid2 <- df[min.2dists[2,],"hhid"]
df$dist2 <- apply(dists, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = FALSE)[3])
```

Output:

```
#    hhid longitude latitude hhid1        dist1 hhid2        dist2
# 1  2004 -1.478302 12.10552  2006 1.700741e-03  2009 0.0021825687
# 2  2006 -1.477470 12.10701  2009 1.017287e-03  2012 0.0015574895
# 3  2009 -1.476489 12.10674  2012 6.502012e-04  2006 0.0010172867
# 4  2012 -1.476147 12.10618  2009 6.502012e-04  2013 0.0007202307
# 5  2013 -1.475480 12.10645  2012 7.202307e-04  2009 0.0010472445
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you used the `spatstat` command `nndist` to compute the nearest-neighbour distances, you could just use the corresponding command `nnwhich` to obtain the identifiers (serial numbers) of the nearest neighbours.

However, latitude and longitude coordinates cannot be treated as x and y coordinates. Even in a small region of the globe, one unit of latitude is not the same distance as one unit of longitude.

Future versions of `spatstat` will handle latitude/longitude coordinates. For now, you are probably better advised to use the `sp` and `rgeos` packages as described in the separate answer by jpsmith.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use `spatstat` for further analysis you need to project to
planar coordinates first and then you can use `nnwhich()` as described by
@adrian-baddely. Note that there is no universaly best coordinate reference
system (CRS) to use, so it requires a choice from you. There is an R package
`crsuggest` that can help you find relevant ones. Here I use UTM zone 30N
which covers all of Burkina Faso as far as I can tell (`srid=32630`):

```r
library(sf)
library(spatstat)

hhid <- c(2004L, 2006L, 2009L, 2012L, 2013L, 2020L, 
          2022L, 2023L, 2028L, 2029L, 2035L, 2036L, 2043L, 2046L, 2047L, 
          2059L, 2062L, 2063L, 2065L, 2066L)
longitude <- c(-1.478302479, 
              -1.477469802, -1.476488709, -1.476146936, -1.47547996, -1.475799441, 
              -1.475903392, -1.476232767, -1.476053953, -1.477196693, -1.476906657, 
              -1.478778243, -1.480723381, -1.433436394, -1.433033824, -1.428791046, 
              -1.431989908, -1.432058454, -1.43134892, -1.430848002) 
latitude <- c(12.10552216, 
              12.10700512, 12.10673618, 12.10618305, 12.10645485, 12.10846806, 
              12.1080761, 12.10830975, 12.11114883, 12.11076546, 12.11197853, 
              12.11345387, 12.10725021, 12.1183548, 12.11699867, 12.11466122, 
              12.1154108, 12.11545277, 12.11554337, 12.11567497)
data <- data.frame(hhid, longitude, latitude)

dat_gps <- st_as_sf(data, crs = 4326, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))
dat_proj <- st_transform(dat_gps, crs = 32630)
dat_ppp <- as.ppp(dat_proj)
ids <- marks(dat_ppp)

nd <- nndist(dat_ppp, k = 1:2)
nw <- nnwhich(dat_ppp, k = 1:2)
```

The “serial number” in `spatstat` will just be the index of the given point
in the order the points are listed. Below are these as well as `hhid`:

```r
data.frame(round(nd,2), nw, hhid = ids, dist.1.hhid = ids[nw[,1]], dist.2.hhid = ids[nw[,2]])
#>    dist.1 dist.2 which.1 which.2 hhid dist.1.hhid dist.2.hhid
#> 1  187.42 238.78       2       3 2004        2006        2009
#> 2  110.86 170.31       3       4 2006        2009        2012
#> 3   71.61 110.86       4       2 2009        2012        2006
#> 4   71.61  78.58       3       5 2012        2009        2013
#> 5   78.58 114.13       4       3 2013        2012        2009
#> 6   44.81  50.31       7       8 2020        2022        2023
#> 7   44.20  44.81       8       6 2022        2023        2020
#> 8   44.20  50.31       7       6 2023        2022        2020
#> 9  130.53 131.42      11      10 2028        2035        2029
#> 10 131.42 137.85       9      11 2029        2028        2035
#> 11 130.53 137.85       9      10 2035        2028        2029
#> 12 261.03 343.62      11      10 2036        2035        2029
#> 13 325.55 355.20       1       2 2043        2004        2006
#> 14 156.28 354.33      15      18 2046        2047        2063
#> 15 156.28 201.28      14      18 2047        2046        2063
#> 16 250.42 295.03      20      19 2059        2066        2065
#> 17   8.79  71.30      18      19 2062        2063        2065
#> 18   8.79  77.88      17      19 2063        2062        2065
#> 19  56.44  71.30      20      17 2065        2066        2062
#> 20  56.44 127.69      19      17 2066        2065        2062
```