# Count 5 highest values of a variable

Tags: r, max

I am using R to try to get each user's top 5 favourite songs by which songs they play the most. I currently have code which counts the highest played song but I was wondering how to get the next 4 highest played songs for that user, presuming every user has played at least 5 songs. Would I have to eliminate the highest values from the dataset and run it again or is there an easier way?

```
write.csv(group_by(mydata,userId) %.%
summarise(favourite=max(playCount)), file="test.csv")
```

An example of the data looks like this

```
userId      songId            playCount
A           568r              85
A           711g              18
C           34n               18
E           454j              65
D           663a              72
B           35d               84
A           34c               72
A           982s              65
E           433f              11
A           565t              7
```

Comment: Related: [*Fastest way to find second (third…) highest/lowest value in vector or column*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
rev(sort(x))[1:n]
```

to get the top `n` values of a vector.  If you wanted the top `n` unique values, just add a call to `unique()`

```
rev(sort(unique(x)))[1:n]
```

Comment: It might speed things up a little bit to use the `partial` argument to `sort.int` (which `sort` calls).  Also instead of using `rev` you could set `decreasing=TRUE`, or just use `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way...

```
library(dplyr)

mydata2 <- group_by(mydata, userId) %.%
              arrange(userId, -playCount) %.%
              mutate(rank = rank(-playCount)) %.%

              # remove `rank > 1` if you want to keep the first song
              filter(rank > 1, rank < 6) %.%

              select(userId, songId, playCount)
```