# R: fast determine top k maximum value in a matrix

Tags: r

I would like to fast determine top k maximum values in a matrix, and then put those not the top k maximum value as zero, currently I work out the following solution. Can somebody improve these one, since when the matrix have many many rows, this one is not so fast?

thanks.

```
mat <- matrix(c(5, 1, 6, 4, 9, 1, 8, 9, 10), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
sortedMat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, method =    "quick")))
topK <- 2
sortedMat <- sortedMat[, 1:topK, drop = FALSE]
lmat <- mat
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  lmat[i, ] <- mat[i, ] %in% sortedMat[i, ]
}
kMat <- mat * lmat

 > mat
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    1    6
[2,]    4    9    1
[3,]    8    9   10

> kMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    0    6
[2,]    4    9    0
[3,]    0    9   10
```

Comment: I don't see what this would have to do with Rcpp so I removed the `rcpp` tag you had there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel He probably wants a faster version with `rcpp`

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel. I just want to know if have a smarter way to do this. Not asking for code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rank` to speed this up. In case there are ties, you would have to decide on a method to break these (e.g. `ties.method  = "random"`).

```
kmat <- function(mat, k){
  mat[t(apply(mat, 1, rank)) <= (ncol(mat)-k)] <- 0
  mat
}
kmat(mat, 2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    5    0    6
## [2,]    4    9    0
## [3,]    0    9   10
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rfast the command **sort_mat** sorts the columns of a matrix, **colOrder** does order for each column, **colRanks** gives ranks for each column and the **colnth** gives the nth value for each column. I believe at least one of them suit you.

Comment: The code:    `mat * (rowRanks(mat) > 1)`  is OK. Thanks @Mike.