# How to get the second smallest/largest element in a list

Tags: r, list

I am looking for a way to get the second(third, fourth etc.) smallest/ largest element of a list in R. Using which.min / which.max I came up with the following solution for the second largest element:

```
test <- c(9,1,3,5,2,4,10)
(test[-which.max(test)])[which.max(test[-which.max(test)])]]
```

However, this is ugly and does not really scale up. Is there a better way to get the x smallest/largest element/value of a list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column this looks relevant, but I'm still not seeing any of the O(n) solutions implemented, partial sort is still O(nlogn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sort, and then an index, to find the n-th smallest element:

```
sort(test)[n]
```

For the second smallest element, use `n=2`:

```
sort(test)[2]
```

Comment: Of course :-) And to get the index combining it with match works perfectly. match(sort(test, decreasing=TRUE)[2],test). Thx.

Comment: this answer certainly works, but if you're sorting to find just one element, it seems like you're being a bit inefficient. Searching for the nth highest element should be O(N), not O(nlogn)