# Find the second minimum value in R

Tags: r

For example,`a <- c(1,1,2,3,4,3,2)` , the second minimum value is **2**, how can I find this second minimum value ?

Comment: Just sort the unique values and take the second one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column

Comment: You will need unique values for partial sorting to work here.

Comment: `min( a[a!=min(a)] )` is work,thank you !