# R how to get a vector contaninig an average of n largest values from the last m values?

Tags: r, vectorization

Say I have this small data set in R.

```
Data = c(8,2,9,7,8,8,9,8,4,9,9,7,2,5,2,2,1,9,9,7)
```

So I am looking to get the average of the 2'nd 3'rd and 4'th smallest and largest values from the last 10 where all values the 10 and ranks should be variable.

In Excel the formula for the mins would be `=AVERAGE(SMALL(A11:A20,ROW(INDIRECT("2:4"))))`
Entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

And the expected result is

```
val min    max
8   NA     NA
2   NA      NA
9   NA      NA
7   NA      NA
8   NA      NA
8   NA      NA
9   NA      NA
8   NA      NA
4   NA      NA
9   6.3333  8.6667
9   6.3333  9
7   7.3333  9
2   6       8.6667
5   5.3333  8.6667
2   3.6667  8.6667
2   2.6667  8.6666
1   2       8
9   2       8.3333
9   2       9
7   2       8.3333
```

In r this seems fairly simple, I get the 10 or x values sort the values and then average or do whatever operation on the appropriate 3 values, which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column)

The problem is that I can only do this in a loop which is slow. Ho can I get such complicated operations in a vectored function?

Comment: Thanks Justin, how did you create the buttons like that? Did you have to manually add the <kbd> tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know how much of a speed improvement is, but `rollapply()` from `zoo` is an option.

```
library(zoo)

mmavg <- function(x) {
    len <- length(x)
    sorted <- sort(x)
    c(min=mean(sorted[2:4]), max=mean(sorted[(len-3):(len-1)]))
}

cbind(val=Data, rollapplyr(Data, 10, mmavg, fill=NA))

#  val      min      max
#    8       NA       NA
#    2       NA       NA
#    9       NA       NA
#    7       NA       NA
#    8       NA       NA
#    8       NA       NA
#    9       NA       NA
#    8       NA       NA
#    4       NA       NA
#    9 6.333333 8.666667
#    9 6.333333 9.000000
#    7 7.333333 9.000000
#    2 6.000000 8.666667
#    5 5.333333 8.666667
#    2 3.666667 8.666667
#    2 2.666667 8.666667
#    1 2.000000 8.000000
#    9 2.000000 8.333333
#    9 2.000000 9.000000
#    7 2.000000 8.333333
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Can you explain why I need rollapplyr vs rollapply. It sounds simple but I cannot find a good explanation when to use which one? Thank again.

Comment: @MichaelE: The 'r' just stands for 'right aligned'. rollapply(..., align="right") will work the same, the former is just a bit more compact.

Comment: I have found an issue when applying it to larger data. Is there a reason rollapply fails for dataframes? cbind(val=as.data.frame(Data), rollapplyr(as.data.frame(Data), 10, mmavg, fill=NA)) gives me a long single vector instead of a matrix with a warning dim<-.zoo`(`*tmp*`, value = c(length(z), 1)). Any ideas or should I ask another question.

Comment: I got it, my data was a 1xn matrix instead or a vector so I needed to add , by.column = FALSE to rollapply and then it works because a matrix is not the same as a vector??

Comment: Yes. Vectors, matrices and single column data frames are treated as separate data classes in R. It can get a bit confusing.