# Find first, second, and third maximum of each row and their corresponding column names in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, max, row

I am trying to find first max, second max, and third max value and corresponding col names for each row, but unable to do that in r. Please help.

Here is how the dataframe looks like:

```
              X1    X2    X3   X4    X5   X6   X7    X8    X9    X10   X11  X12   
      10003   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0       
      10006   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0 16.7   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0       
      10007   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0       
      10008   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0       
      10010   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0       
      10014   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Your data seems to be all zeros except for one value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: It is a massive data frame, I just posted first few rows and fewer columns.

Comment: Your dataset is not reproducible and your question is vague.

Comment: and10003,10006 etc are rows names, not values .I tried to run with apply function across rows but it does not give me the colnames

Comment: The question's title says "max" and the text says "min"!

Comment: Tried this, but has error

Comment: Outdata<-setNames(
  data.frame(
    t(apply(mat1_2_df, 1, function(x) {
      ind <- which.max(x)[1]
      c(ind, x[ind]) })),
    t(apply(mat1_2_df, 1, function(x) {
      ind2<-which.max(x[-ind])[1]
      c(ind2, x[ind2])})),
    t(apply(mat1_2_df, 1, function(x) {
        ind3<-which.max(x[-c(ind,ind2)])
        c(ind3, x[ind3])}))
   
), c(  "First","Value","Second","value2","Third","value3"))

Comment: Sorry it is max values

Comment: Have you looked at? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column

Comment: yes, I looked at this, but unable to replicate on the dataframe. I will add some more rows

Comment: it does not allow me to add more rows, I am trying to get the max, second max and third max and corresponding column names and in case these are zeros then still get at least one corresponding colname against 0.0 values.

Comment: I have made up this dataframe to illustrate it better.

Comment: x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9
1003a 0 45.7 0 22.9 0 13.7 0 0 23.1
1004a 22.2 0 13.2 0 5.4 0 9.7 0 0
1005a 0 0 0 12 2.1 0 0 3.2 0
1006a 1.2 0 1.2 0 43.9 43.9 0 0 57.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample data you posted in your comment:

```
data <-read.table(text="       x1    x2    x3     x4    x5    x6   x7   x8    x9
                        1003    0  45.7     0   22.9     0  13.7    0    0  23.1 
                        1004 22.2     0  13.2      0   5.4     0  9.7    0     0 
                        1005    0     0     0     12   2.1     0    0  3.2     0  
                        1006  1.2     0   1.2      0  43.9  43.9    0    0  57.6",
                    header=T)
```

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyverse` to acheive this.

---

The following code will give you the maximum three columns across all the rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(column, value, -rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  head(3)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   rowname [3]
#   rowname column value
#   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 1006    x9      57.6
# 2 1003    x2      45.7
# 3 1006    x5      43.9
```

---

If you want to get the maximum three values for each row, you can do it as follows:

```
result <- data %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(column, value, -rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  mutate(max = rank(-value)) %>%
  filter(max <= 3) %>% 
  arrange(rowname, max)
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   rowname [4]
#    rowname column value   max
#    <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 1003    x2      45.7   1  
#  2 1003    x9      23.1   2  
#  3 1003    x4      22.9   3  
#  4 1004    x1      22.2   1  
#  5 1004    x3      13.2   2  
#  6 1004    x7       9.7   3  
#  7 1005    x4      12     1  
#  8 1005    x8       3.2   2  
#  9 1005    x5       2.1   3  
# 10 1006    x9      57.6   1  
# 11 1006    x5      43.9   2.5
# 12 1006    x6      43.9   2.5
```

---

To summarize the result for each row, use the following code:

```
result %>% 
  mutate(result = paste0(column, "=", value, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  select(result) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   rowname [4]
#   rowname result                   
#   <chr>   <chr>                    
# 1 1003    x2=45.7, x9=23.1, x4=22.9
# 2 1004    x1=22.2, x3=13.2, x7=9.7 
# 3 1005    x4=12, x8=3.2, x5=2.1    
# 4 1006    x9=57.6, x5=43.9, x6=43.9
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any simple way to do this as I am new and unable to understand the above code and I am looking to get six columns against each row of dataframe, three giving max,second max,third max and also with their collnames(e.g. 45.7,x2,23.1,x9,22.9,x4) for the first row.

Comment: I see what you mean. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
max.names = apply(data, 1, function(x) names(sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:3]))
max.vals = apply(data, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:3])
data = cbind(data, t(max.names), t(max.vals))
#        x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6  x7  x8   x9  1  2  3    1    2    3
# 1003  0.0 45.7  0.0 22.9  0.0 13.7 0.0 0.0 23.1 x2 x9 x4 45.7 23.1 22.9
# 1004 22.2  0.0 13.2  0.0  5.4  0.0 9.7 0.0  0.0 x1 x3 x7 22.2 13.2  9.7
# 1005  0.0  0.0  0.0 12.0  2.1  0.0 0.0 3.2  0.0 x4 x8 x5 12.0  3.2  2.1
# 1006  1.2  0.0  1.2  0.0 43.9 43.9 0.0 0.0 57.6 x9 x5 x6 57.6 43.9 43.9
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach:

```
 # Make up data because yours is pretty unreproducible:
 df <- data.frame(X1=1:5, X2=c(3,5,1,6,7))

 # combine and sort the data by decreasing value:
 a <- sort(dplyr::combine(df), decreasing = T)[1:3]

 # For loop to get the indexes:
 for(i in 1:length(a)){
    print(which(df==a[i], arr.ind = T))
 }
```

This will give you what you need. Replace `print` with whatever you want to do (eg assign or whatever you need)